# protobuf-net -- DataContractSurrogates?

Tags: c#, wcf, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, datacontractsurrogate

Right now, I'm using `DataContractSerializer` along with `DataContractSurrogate` to provide serialization descriptions for NHibernate proxy classes (as described in http://timvasil.com/blog14/post/2008/02/WCF-serialization-with-NHibernate.aspx).

I'm really interested in switching to *protobuf-net* to serialize my data using protobufs, but I can't seem to find a way to consume the `DataContractSurrogate`'s. Without this feature, I'm dead in the water for serializing NHibernate dynamic proxy classes that derive from my model classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not a NHibernate expert, but in v2 there are a few things designed to cater for this scenario; foremost there is code built in intended to recognise NH proxies and treat appropriately (in particular, not complain about unknown types).

I will read the linked article, though; without more NH experience I can't be sure that the current approach is sufficient. I would also be more than happy to receive any test cases I could use to prove that it meets the need.

Comment: In this case its not NHibernate specific... basically the need is to be able to have a derived class **b** be serialized as if it is base class **a** without any attention paid to the fact that we are really dealing with an instance of a child class (and without any ability to list these derived classes as known types).

Comment: @David well, actually it *is*, because I need to know what is a fake *proxy* (fine), vs an unexpected subtype (not fine, since it is an inheritance aware serializer). At the moment I look for the marker interface `NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy` - which is, I suspect you'll agree, pretty specific ;p

Comment: OK, I get what you're saying. Perhaps just introduce an attribute the says that all subclasses should be ignored unless they're known?